# Is it possible to control app volume from taskbar?

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control

I currently have Pulse Audio Volume Control and I'm using it to control audio between my laptop & external monitor as well as volume of different apps.

Is there a faster way of controlling these (especially app volumes), from the music/sound taskbar for example?

I am open to experiment with other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of writing I have not found a solution for Ubuntu Unity. But having just moved to Ubuntu Gnome I was glad to find out several that are part of the Gnome desktop in the form of an extension:

- [Laine](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/937/laine/).
  It controls the volume of the application in Pulse Audio not the native application volume.

[image]

- [Volume Mixer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/858/volume-mixer/)
- ([Media player indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/)) for media players which supposedly has volume control but I haven't seen it yet. Maybe I need a reboot.

On a related topic the [Gnome Shell Audio Output Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1028/gnome-shell-audio-output-switcher/) is handy to switch between audio outputs.

After trying the above I ended up with [Volume Mixer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/858/volume-mixer/) and [Gnome Shell Audio Output Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1028/gnome-shell-audio-output-switcher/). Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Volume Mixer worked for me, too.